# React-Native Build Failed app:mergeDebugAssets

Tags: android, react-native

I completed a react-native app for Android, and now when I try to

> run npm android, I get this error:

```
 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException:
C:\Users\SONY\AwesomeProject\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_assets\debug\mergeDebugAssets\out\fonts
```

Please can you help me?

Many Thanks

React-native

Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Users\SONY\AwesomeProject\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_assets\debug\mergeDebugAssets\out\fonts
        at com.android.ide.common.resources.MergedAssetWriter$AssetWorkAction.run(MergedAssetWriter.java:84)
        ... 1 more

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.

  > Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException:
  >   C:\Users\SONY\AwesomeProject\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_assets\debug\mergeDebugAssets\out\fonts

I want to successfully build the android app

Comment: Hi Judy, were you able to solve this issue? I am facing a similar issue

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try running this inside your project directory:

1. cd android
2. gradlew clean
3. cd..
4. react-native run-android

Comment: ./gradlew clean

Comment: sometimes `./gradlew clean `doesn't work so try `.\gradlew clean`

Comment: ./ is used for terminals(e.g. VS Code Terminal) and on cmd you need to run it without ./

Answer (score 12):

I had this issue and for me `./gradlew clean` didn't help.

But I found a file called `assets` in `android/app/src/main` that git showed as untracked. When I removed the assets file I could build the project without problems again.

I use Android Studio for debugging java code and I would guess that is why the assets file was created.

Answer (score 4):

For Linux / MacOS- `./gradlew clean`

Windows PowerShell- `.\gradlew clean`

Windows cmd- `gradlew clean`

Comment: I am on Windows and the command "gradlew clean" worked for me.

Comment: This solution works for me. from the root directory, change the directory to android using "cd android" command and do "./gradlew clean". Then run "yarn android"

Answer (score 4):

If you have installed react-native-vector-icons, try to unlink it by using this command

> **react-native unlink react-native-vector-icons**

Answer (score 1):

Go to android/app/build.gradle, add the following lines of codes:

```
dependencies {
   implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3' //enter the latest version 
}
android {
  defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true // This code line
  }
}
```

Then run again, it'll work.
I tried and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing worked for me, just created a new project and copied all of my work to it, and finally it worked.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, files that were present in android\app\scr\main\assets\fonts folder were causing error after deleting them error goes away and app is also working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I upgraded the react-native-vector-icons package.

Here's what I did:

1. Go to android/app/src/main/assets/fonts/*
2. Delete only files that are related to the library for example - Entypo.ttf, EvilIcons.ttf, MaterialIcons.ttf etc.
   *For backup purposes you can copy the resources in some other directory.
3. Build again.

Answer (score 0):

do `./gradlew clean`
then `rm -rf android/app/src/main/assets`

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?