# Mapbox - FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. (Flutter)

Tags: android, flutter, mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-android

I am using mapbox gl demo for my flutter application and getting below error at the time of running my flutter application in Android device :

> > FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
>
> > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> > Could not resolve com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-accounts:0.7.0.
> > Required by:
> > project :app > project :mapbox_gl > com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.2.0
> > > Could not resolve com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-accounts:0.7.0.
> > > Could not get resource 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/mapbox-android-accounts/0.7.0/mapbox-android-accounts-0.7.0.pom'.
> > > Could not GET 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/mapbox-android-accounts/0.7.0/mapbox-android-accounts-0.7.0.pom'.
> > Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 2m 51s [!] Gradle threw an error while downloading
> artifacts from the network. Retrying Gradle Build: #1, wait time:
> 100ms Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

**Referring this link to integrate** : https://github.com/flutter-mapbox-gl/maps#downloading-offline-regions

What might be issue? Thanks.

Comment: Check below, May be this can help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56581591/react-native-build-failed-appmergedebugassets

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to your `android/build.gradle` under section `allprojects/repositories`

```
  maven {
    url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
    authentication {
        basic(BasicAuthentication)
    }
    credentials {
        // Do not change the username below.
        // This should always be `mapbox` (not your username). 
        username = 'mapbox'
        // Use the secret token you stored in gradle.properties as the password
        password = project.properties['MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN'] ?: ""
    }
}
```

Got this hint from here [https://github.com/rnmapbox/maps/issues/1501#issuecomment-906158991](https://github.com/rnmapbox/maps/issues/1501)